# ContentType issue in headers in POST request (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, post, header

0

I have a problem probably with the parameter ContentType in POST method in Dart. I'm trying to make API call to change the value of **expires_in** in body (default value:3600). But it seems like Android **cannot read Content Type from headers**, because I have the same result in Android Studio and Postman when I inactive the ContentType header in Postman. When this header is active in Postman it returns the expires_in changed value properly. Where could be a mistake? In passing headers?

Dart code:

```
Future<http.Response> getPrivateKeyResponse(Uri url) async {
    var customerKey = "***";
    var customerSecret = "***";
    var encode = base64Encode(utf8.encode("$customerKey:$customerSecret"));

    return await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://api.dolby.io/v1/auth/token'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Authorization":"Basic $encode",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        "grant_type":"client_credentials",
        "expires_in":7200
      }),
    );
  }
```

Screenshot from Postman result with changed value to 7200 with active ContentType header (correct result):[image][image]

Screenshot from Postman result with changed value to 7200 with inactive ContentType header (wrong result):[image][image]

And with inactive ContentType header it returns the same result as Android Studio with code above (wrong result):
[image]

So it brings me to thinking that passing this ContentType in headers not working properly. Do you have any suggestions? Or maybe the code is wrong on the Dart side?

Comment: `http` library automatically converts the header name to lower-case, may your server not accepting lower-case header name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check postman to give you the exact code to generate the same working request in dart. There is a code button (probably will be on the top right side) to show you the code in different languages, choose dart and check if you're missing anything.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about this function in Postman, it actually works after using this code. Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem bro, you learn a new thing everyday. Happy coding